# Google Maps - Use fitBounds on KML polygon fusion table layer

Tags: google-maps-api, google-fusion-tables

I have seen example here how to use map.fitBounds on fusiontablelayer
[here](http://www.geocodezip.com/www_vciregionmap_comC.html) and [here](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTablesLayer_centerOnMarkers.html) , but I think it works with markers table only. Its impossible to parse the lat and long when the vertex coordinates are in the geometry column as in a kml polygon layer.

Is there a solution to use fitBounds or other function to zoom to the extent of a kml polygon fusion table layer?

Comment: Accepted Answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955644/google-maps-api-v3-kml-plus-additional-marker-not-zooming-to-fit-both answered by Geocodezip

Comment: I'd recommend moving this over to stackoverflow.

Comment: @Mapperz: its not an answer to my question... kmllayer is not fusiontablelayer

Comment: You can Centre the fusiontablelayer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434685/determine-center-bounding-box-of-fusiontableslayer-in-google-maps-api

Comment: As I said, this method works only with markers fusiontablelayer. Not KML polygon loaded in fusiontablelayer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You are correct. Currently the functionality to zoom/fit bounds does not exist for polygon or line data from fusion tables. You will need to use the GVIZ (Google Visualization API) and the geoxml3 parser. I used some of the code from the following applications. One is a [polygon](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/www_advocacy_ucla_edu_Assembly_MapC.html) example and the other is a [line/arc](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/indianatrails_com_fusiontables_map.html) example.

There is a [post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/fusion-tables-users-group/y-CX9VUw_S8/sgZZ8bRvjbcJ) in the Google Fusion Tables group pointing out that the functionality is not there (yet). I had the same problem and I managed to get my application working recycling some of the code from the examples above. Hope it helps.

**Update**: Google Fusion Tables is being turned down in December 2019.

https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/9185417

Consider moving to [GeoJSON](https://geojson.org/) for markers/lines and [TopoJSON](https://github.com/topojson/topojson) for complex polygons.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works for me. However, have you found a way to have the extent of all rows/features of the kml and not only one at a time in order to have the bounds of the entire table?

Comment: @DemarsM. Fusion Tables uses the ST_INTERSECTS to find map features within a defined area. This may work. I have not tested it myself. I need to do the same for some of my queries so I will give this a try soon. I thought it was deprecated but apparently it is not. Failing that I would think that creating a KML that is a 'box' containing your area and adding to the table may work for your selection(s). Another possibility is parsing the rows necessary to capture the entire area. These are just guesses/suggestions at this point.

Comment: I dont know about ST_INTERSECTS. If you can do something interresting with that let me know. However, take a look a the second example, the one with line/arc. It shows how to zoom on the entire kml using union(). It works with polygon kml too.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I totally missed that (or more like was not looking for it at the time). I'll give it a try. Cheers.

Comment: any code snippet for the union solution you can post here? thx

Comment: In the line/arc example above you will find the UNION code example in the 'ZoomTo' function. In the source code it looks like this: bounds.union(geoXml.docs[0].gpolygons[0].bounds);

Comment: @ValNeekman. Not sure if you ever ventured to the examples provided. I stripped out the polylines and markers as they do not exist in my data.  
`if (geoXml.docs[0].gpolygons.length > 0) { geoXml.docs[0].gpolygons[0].setMap(null);  if (i==0) var bounds = geoXml.docs[0].gpolygons[0].bounds; else bounds.union(geoXml.docs[0].gpolygons[0].bounds);}`